# cannot open Anaconda prompt after updating conda

Tags: anaconda, conda

After updating the anaconda3 with conda command, the `Anaconda3 Prompt` cannot be opened successfully. And I found the `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat` is missing.

```
    'C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How to repair this?

Comment: Which version of Anaconda were you updating from?

Comment: Hi @ally-e, thanks for comments. I use both 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repair a damaged installation using an Anaconda installer with the silent install steps, https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/silent-mode/. For you case something like this would work, be sure to download a new installer, https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/.

```
start /wait "" Downloads/Anaconda3-4.4.0-Windows-x86_64.exe /InstallationType=JustMe /RegisterPython=0 /S /D=%UserProfile%\Anaconda3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your answer! Finally I solved the problem as follows: install a new anaconda into a new directory, then copy the activate.bat and deactivate.bat files into the Scripts directory of previous anaconda.

Comment: I've verified your method and it also works! But I have concerns that this seems to reinstall the anaconda again, wouldn't this damage the package dependencies on the have-installed packages on the old anaconda? But it seems not. Previously I installed the tensorflow and after following your method, the tensorflow can still be loaded (but before that I thought the packages which the tensorflow dependes on would be replaced by the old packages). Thus this method also works well. Thanks a lot!